# Visual Attribute no Oracle Forms Personalization

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Estou tendo um problema com o *Forms Personalization*, sou iniciante no Oracle EBS e no *Forms Personalization*.

Preciso alterar a cor de fundo do meu item, mas quando eu uso a propriedade `background-color`, ele muda toda a coluna, eu quero apenas o item, pois ele já foi verificado na minha condição. Eu encontrei na internet, pessoas recomendando usar a propriedade `VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE (INSTANCE-ITEM)`, mas eu não sei como usar, o que eu devo colocar em `Valor`?

Talvez as fotos ajudem vocês a me ajudarem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: O oracle EBS que eu uso é o 11g